# Studio audio mixing software for Ubuntu

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

Any software for audio files mixing like [MixMeister](http://www.mixmeister.com/) does?

- manual ordering
- volume and low-mid-hi adjusting levels
- able to export to .mp3 file
- BPM's track adjust
- VST effects, per track desirable

(and the last but less important)

- save session for future modifications

Note: currently, due to my computer capabilities, there's no option for a virtual machine

Answer (score 3):

Check [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) if it fits the bill (though I doubt if it have some of the requirements mentioned). If not then try [Ardour](http://ardour.org/) or Just Run FL Studio on wine.
I had one time FL 9 Running fine on wine (DEMO). Have not tried this for Cakewalk Sonar, Cubase nor the Like. For All Available Audio Recording software on Linux check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_audio_software#Recording.2C_editing_and_mastering) page and decide for yourself. Also  here is interesting link, not sure about the software [BigTwig](http://www.ubuntuvibes.com/2012/01/bitwig-professional-music-creation.html) though!

Comment: I'll check out all, specially the software list.